# How to send sms from second sim card in android for all version

Tags: android, smsmanager

Thank you for review my question.

Now i have problem to send sms from my mobile. i could not access to send sms from both sim card but only primary sim card to use send sms.

Question: How can i use secondary sim card to send sms?

Question: How to get dual sim card information using TelephonyManager in all android version?
I got only one sim card information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple SIM API is supported only from Lollipop. The phones, which have more than 1 sim, and run on older Android versions have custom ROMs(firmware), edited by their manufacturers to support multi-sim. All they have different API, which is possibly not accessible for third-party apps like yours (only system apps can use it). So if you want something like that to work on all devices, you will have to get the ROMs of all devices, decompile it, and see how the manufacturers modified it. Than you will have to implement different ways to do that for every phone model.

So in other words - it's impossible.